# IE sometimes won't fire onload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I have this code loaded in a script in the body:

```
(function() {
attach = function() {
       blablablablbalabl;
};

if (window.addEventListener){  
    window.addEventListener('load', attach, false);   
} else if (window.attachEvent){      
    window.attachEvent('onload', attach);  
}  
})();
```

Problem is, sometimes (4 out of 5 tries) I am refreshing IE, it wont do `attach()`,
while in other browsers it calls 100% of the times!

I am getting crazy!

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is the attachEvent part and not whatever you're doing in `attach()` ?

Comment: yes. i put alert inside attach to see it is called. but its not!

Comment: What is calling your function, (function())() isn't going to execute itself.

Comment: Yes it is.... its function()....

Comment: Does whatever you did in your `onload` function work when using jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` method?

Comment: I tried. and sometimes i get "Object doesn't support this property or method" (on the ready())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery uses a few tricks to solve this problem.

It attaches itself to `onreadystatechange` as well as `onload`.

```
    // If IE event model is used
    } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
        // ensure firing before onload,
        // maybe late but safe also for iframes
        document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded);

        // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
        window.attachEvent( "onload", jQuery.ready );

        // If IE and not a frame
        // continually check to see if the document is ready
        var toplevel = false;

        try {
            toplevel = window.frameElement == null;
        } catch(e) {}

        if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && toplevel ) {
            doScrollCheck();
        }
    }
```

In addition, it continually checks if the page can be scrolled. Once the DOM has loaded, the page becomes scrollable, thus `jQuery.ready` is triggered.

```
// The DOM ready check for Internet Explorer
function doScrollCheck() {
    if ( jQuery.isReady ) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        // If IE is used, use the trick by Diego Perini
        // http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/
        document.documentElement.doScroll("left");
    } catch(e) {
        setTimeout( doScrollCheck, 1 );
        return;
    }

    // and execute any waiting functions
    jQuery.ready();
}
```

You could try and implement this behavior in your app or use jQuery directly.

Comment: I would vote for using jQuery directly as reimplementing all this stuff yourself is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Internet Explorer heaven... Can't we just stop using it?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
(function() {
var callback = null;
attach = function() {
       blablablablbalabl;
       callback.apply();

};
callback = window.onload;
window.onload = attach;
})();
```

Comment: I am not very sure. I have faced this problem a few times when setting onload even for image object. The onload event will not trigger, if the image is loaded from cache.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar recently where an external script that setup a listener to the load event was not firing in IE.

I noticed that if I inlined the script into the document body then it would fire reliably. Lead me to believe it was a race condition of some sort, where the onload event would fire before the external script was fully parsed.

Other things to check is whether there is another script cancelling the event propagation and whether your function callback is throwing an exception in IE, like incorrectly assuming what 'this' point to